# Maximum height of bullet shot straight up

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, projectile

> "Consider a hypothetical dense astronomical object with a mass of $2 × 10^{30}$ kg (about the mass of the sun), and a radius of $1.4 × 10^{14}$ m. Assuming you could stand on the surface of this object, if you fired a gun straight into the air, how high above the surface would the bullet go before turning around? The mass of a bullet is $5.0$ g and its speed is $800$ m/s
> when it leaves the gun. Ignore any frictional or drag forces on the bullet."

I attempted to solve this question using kinematics. I found the acceleration due to gravity using $g = \frac{GMm}{r^2}$, which equals $6.8 × 10^{-9}$. I plugged this value along with the initial velocity 800 m/s into $h=\frac{v^2}{2g}$ and got $4.71 × 10^{13}$. The correct answer in the answer key is actually $7.1 × 10^{13}$ and they solved it using conserrvation of energy (using gravitational potential energy). I don't understand why the kinematics method gave a different answer compared to the energy conservation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you travel $4.71 \times 10^{13}$ meters from an object with radius $1.4 \times 10^{14}$ meters, you cannot treat $g$ as a constant. $g$ is a measure of the strength of the gravity you feel, and should be expected to vary with distance because the force of gravity varies with distance. It's just that if you move for a very small distance relative to the radius (e.g. 10 meters on the Earth against a radius of 6400 km) then the variation is infinitesimal.

What this actually means is that once you get an answer of $4.71 \times 10^{13}$, you should realize that the equation $h = v^2/2g$ is not valid. You need to either do the calculus with $g$ depending on $r$, or take the shortcut and apply conservation of energy.

Note that the answer key's conservation of energy undoubtedly used $PE = -GMm/r$ instead of $PE = mgh$ for the same reason of $g$ not being a constant.